# Content Delivery in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, content-delivery

We are in the process of migrating the our Salesforce instance from classic to lightning. Just realized that the Content delivery is not supported in lightning. Can anyone suggest me what the work around for achieving this in lightning. I also looked in to the Salesforce documentation

`In Lightning Email generates delivery-based links as email attachments for Lightning Experience users who have access to the Content Deliveries feature.`

I am not able to understand how Email generates delivery-based links as email attachments, can anyone point me to any links/details to understand this in lightning

Comment: Please provide more detail on your question. Content Delivery for what feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salesforce Admin blog explains how to use the workaround Lightning email solution, refer to this post: [deliver content with Lightning Email](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2016/send-content-easily-lightning-email).

You might as well upvote this Idea [Make Content Delivery functionality available in Lightning Experience](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003X96QAE)